# How to build a raster/raster stack to accept values based on df

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am trying to build some data structures to accept data.

```
r1 = raster(matrix(NA,3,3)) 
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(2,2,2), val = c(10,20,30)) #example of data
```

Then I was hoping to fill this raster with values based on a df. But not like this, but based on the values of `df$a` and `df$b`.

```
plot(r1) #empty
values(r1) <- c(NA, df$val[[1]], NA, NA,df$val[[2]],NA,NA,NA,df$val[[3]]) #unindex filling
plot(r1) #wanted result
```

I hope its clear what I am hoping to achieve. Its geolocation data, and therefore `df$a` and `df$b` will become Lon and Lat, and `df$val` will be an environmental variable. The layers will become monthly averages. Not all raster cells will have variables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a raster and coordinates, you can compute the cell numbers and use these to assign the values. Something like this

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=5, ncols=5, xmn=0, xmx=5, ymn=0, ymx=5) 
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,2,2), val = c(10,20,30))

cells <- cellFromXY(r, df[,1:2])
r[cells] <- df$val
```

Also see `?rasterFromXYZ`